# Elements in $scope missing from form

Tags: angularjs

I have this form (shown after page loads with Angular filled in data):

```
<div ng-controller="ItemsController">
<form name="Items" class="form-horizontal ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-submitted" ng-submit="submit()" _lpchecked="1">
    <input ng-model="item._token" name="_token" type="hidden" value="gej20f0RMOJypfL5n93Mon3QL6PjrrgWgZ20RnGe" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
    <input ng-model="item.no_label" name="no_label" type="hidden" value="1" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Add New Item</legend>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="sku">SKU</label>

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input id="sku" name="sku" ng-model="item.sku" type="text" placeholder="Enter SKU" class="form-control input-md ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched" required="">

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="Name">Name</label>

            <div class="col-md-5">
                <input id="name" name="name" ng-model="item.name" type="text" placeholder="Optional name" class="form-control input-md ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched">

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="add"></label>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <button id="add" name="add" class="btn btn-success">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add
                </button>
                <button id="cancel" name="cancel" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

And this controller:

```
myApp.controller('ItemsController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.item = {};
    $scope.submit = function () {
        if ($scope.validate()) {
            $http.post('/items/store', $scope.item)
                    .success(function (data) {
                        toastr['success']('Added ' + $scope.item.sku + ' to list.', 'Success!');
                        $scope.Items.$setPristine();
                        oTable.ajax.reload();
                    }).error(function (data) {
                        if ('error' in data)
                            toastr['error']('ERROR: ' + data['error'], 'Error!');
                        else
                            toastr['error'](JSON.stringify(data), 'Error!');
                    });
        }
    };
    $scope.validate = function () {
        return $.trim($scope.item.sku) != '';
    };
}]);
```

Everytime I submit this form, the data in `$scope.item` is missing `item._token` and `item.no_label`.

Why and how do I correct this?

Comment: I think these data are missing because of input type is hidden.

Comment: pass item from `ng-submit="submit(item)"` like this and use it inside your submit method..will solve your problem.. `$scope.submit = function (item) {//you can use item model here};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-model` is used for two-way data binding. Since you are using `hidden input elements`, which can not be modified by or shown to users, there is no reason using `ng-model`. The less two-way binding, the better Perf would be.

So the best way to fix this issue is that add `_token` and `no_label` value to `$scope.item` in controller.

```
$scope.item = {
  _token: 'gej20f0RMOJypfL5n93Mon3QL6PjrrgWgZ20RnGe',
  no_label: 1
};
```

If you must add these elements in View, use one-way binding in View

```
<input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{:: item._token}}" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
<input name="no_label" type="hidden" value="{{:: item.no_label}}" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
```

Check this [pr](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/2574) to know more about how Angular guys think about data binding on hidden elements.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the value attribute try using ng-value:

```
<input ng-model="item._token" name="_token" type="hidden" ng-value="gej20f0RMOJypfL5n93Mon3QL6PjrrgWgZ20RnGe" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
<input ng-model="item.no_label" name="no_label" type="hidden" ng-value="1" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
```

Another option is updating item like this:

```
$scope.item = {
  _token: 'gej20f0RMOJypfL5n93Mon3QL6PjrrgWgZ20RnGe',
  no_label: 1
};
```